QR Code weird alphanumeric group conversion
characters corresponding values
When converting something in an alphanumerical mode to a bitstream you first have to

Place them in groups of 2 : (n1, n2).
Convert them as so : (n1's value * 45 + n2's value).
Convert them to a 11-bit binary number : ...
And so on : ...
When converting alphanumeric characters to a number why that formula specifically, and why * 45 and not any other number.

I've tried looking a bit into RS ECC and BCH ECC to see if it were connected,
Read through most QR Code structure guides,
I was expecting for the characters to be converted to the ISO-8599-1 character set's binary version

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].
